# Use a remote certificate (on other computer) for mTLS transaction

Tags: certificates, hardware-token

I have an USB Token (brand 3SKey) containing a certificate "C" with its private key stuck on a machine "A". The certificate's private key is obviously not exportable and I'm not interest into using 3rd party tools to try to extract it.

This certificate is used exclusively to access web resources via mTLS, so that means that all the trafic requiring mTLS must be executed from or redirected to "A", which creates some load issue right now.

Are there any tools which allow the usage of the certificate with its private key in a mTLS context from a remote computer?

I  tried using "certlm.msc" on Windows, but the certificate accessibility is limited to Local Machine while "C" only appeared in Current User.

Note : OS is Windows(Win 10) but I can consider using Linux if necessary

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a programming question, not a security question. You need to program the client application to offload the client authentication to another machine. How to do this depends on what language it's written in and what library(ies) it uses for TLS and cryptography. Note on terminology: the _certificate_ can surely be copied wherever you want: it's public information. The _private key_ is what can't be copied.

Comment: i was missing the point, "the certificate with its private for a mTLS usage"